# How can you pass environment variables to google app engine via app.yaml?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am using Google App Engine to deploy a node app (nextjs, node-12).

To deploy the app, I run:

```
gcloud app deploy
```

My app.yaml is as follows (minus variable substitutions):

```
runtime: nodejs12
env_variables:
  NEXT_PUBLIC_FRONTEND_URL: "A"
```

In my code is the following line:

```
const url = `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FRONTEND_URL}/login/callback`;
```

When this code runs in app engine, url evaluates to B/login/callback

I don't understand this behavior. The documentation here (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref) seems to indicate to me that this should work, but it does not.

Is there a reason for this? I've unset the variables from my local computer, just in case they were somehow getting passed, and I removed the .env file in case nginx was sourcing it or something like that.

Comment: There is no reason, you are doing the thing well. Are you sure that your env var is well created? Are you requesting the latest deployed version? Perform a `gcloud app versions list` get your latest deployed version, be sure to have traffic split to 1.0. then perform a `gcloud app versions descrive <versionid> --service=<service name>` to check the configuration of the service.

Answer (score 1):

What you have done looks correct. Try the following troubleshooting steps

1. Confirm you are not directly setting the value somewhere in your code e.g. say you call a child process and pass an `env` to it and you have explicitly set the value there
2. Check your deployed versions (you can do this via cloud console, see path below). Do you have multiple versions of the app? Which one are you running?

To check your versions and which one is running

`console.cloud.google.com > App Engine > Versions`

To view the configuration for each of the deployed versions,

`select the version and click on 'View' under the 'config' column` . This will display the deployed `app.yaml` file for that version